# Access - Drop Down List Open Form

Tags: forms, combobox, expression, ms-access-2010

Please be gentle, i'm new to access but I'm trying to create a down down list that opens forms. I've done a fair bit of Google searches and not really found anything.

On my ComboBox on both "After Update" and "On Change" I have tried the below code.... Both with and without data in my drop down list.

```
Private Sub Combo1_AfterUpdate()

    Select Case Combo1.Value

        Case "Menu1"
            DoCmd.OpenForm "Form1"
        Case "Menu2"
            DoCmd.OpenForm "Form2"
        Case "Menu3"
            DoCmd.OpenForm "Form3"
End Sub
```

I have also tried;

```
DoCmd.OpenForm Combo1.Value
```

and adding my form names in the ComboBox but that doesn't work either.

Thanks in Advance.

.Lee

Answer (score 0):

I just made a form using the second method that you tried. I wanted to confirm that this is the exact code you were using:

```
Private Sub Combo1_AfterUpdate()
DoCmd.OpenForm Combo1.Value
End Sub
```

This way is easier. (At least in terms of VBA coding). You can use the design tab to put a combo box on the form then select, "I will type in the values I want" you will then make two columns:

```
Column1      Column2
Form1 name   Display Name1
Form2 name   Display Name2
Etc.
```

After you have created the combobox click on the combobox in design view and go to the property sheet (in the Design Tab) and change the column width to 0" that will hide the first column but the value will still be bound to the combobox. It is important to note that the combobox must be two columns for this method to work and when you are entering the values directly into the property sheet on the data tab under row source the same values would look like. ( "Form1 name";"Display Name1";"Form2 Name";"Display Name2" etc. ) This code should work pretty easily but the form names must be exact or it will generate an error. Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Hello rmh, thanks for coming back to me. I have tried the code: 'code' Private Sub Combo1_AfterUpdate() DoCmd.OpenForm Combo1.Value End Sub 'code' and it doesn't work.


I have also tried what you suggested with the two columns and that doesn't work either :( ...   I can select the items from the drop down list but when I click on (for example Display Name 1) nothing happens.  am I missing something?

Comment: Hmm...If the form name is spelled wrong it would generate an error so my guess is that the code is not running. Where are you placing the code for this? You will want to open the form in design view click on the combo box, go to the property sheet from the design tab then on the event tab click on the after update text box then click on the "..." button. This will ask you which builder you want to use and you will select code builder. It will automatically add the first and last line so you just need to add the DoCmd.OpenForm Combo1.Value in the middle(if the name of the Combo Box is "Combo1".

Comment: Hello.  OK... I have no idea why it works on a newly created database... but it does - and it doesn't work on my current database. I'll have a play but thank you so much for all your time and help.  Cheers, Lee

Comment: No Worries just let me know if you need anything else

Comment: I've found out whats been causing my issue... On the Form properties you need to set "Allow Edits" to "Yes" .   Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

Private Sub Combo1_AfterUpdate()

```
Select Case Combo1.Value

    Case "Menu1"
        DoCmd.OpenForm "Form1"
    Case "Menu2"
        DoCmd.OpenForm "Form2"
    Case "Menu3"
        DoCmd.OpenForm "Form3"
End Select 'this was missing in your code'
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks for the code guys, i added the "End Select" statement that was missing and it worked !

Comment: Please provide a detailed explanation to your answer, in order for the next user to understand your answer better.